# Is there a way to wrap the assignment of an object?

Tags: python, attributes, operator-overloading

I'm trying to save the variable as a file whenever it's assigned to a new value. I found that the << operator could be overloaded, so I decided to use that to wrap the object's assignment. However, it throws an Attribute error when I tested it wrapping a string.

Code below:

```
def wrapper(obj, path, mode="text",*args, **kwargs):
    def inner(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        self = value
        # Write to file
        if mode == "text":
            with open(path, "w") as f:
                f.write(self)
        elif mode == "binary":
            with open(path, "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(self, f)
    # Define << operator for object
    setattr(obj, "__lshift__", inner)
    return obj
```

The error it throws:

```
'str' object has no attribute '__lshift__'
```

Comment: string doesn't have operation `<<` so you can't overwrite it. Try `"a" << 2` and you get error.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
def wrapper(obj, path, mode="text",*args, **kwargs):
    def inner(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        self = value
        # Write to file
        if mode == "text":
            with open(path, "w") as f:
                f.write(self)
        elif mode == "binary":
            with open(path, "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(self, f)
    # Define << operator for object
    setattr(obj, "__lshift__", inner)
    return obj
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].